# Include() ThenInclude() throws "Sequence contains more than one matching element" exception in Table Per Hierarchy strategy

Tags: c#, .net, inheritance, entity-framework-core

I am working with Entity Framework 7 and code-first, and I have a model which involves parent-child relations on 3 levels :

- `Corporations` have `companies`
- `Companies` belong to a `corporation` and have `factories`
- `Factories` belong to a `company`

Since these 3 entities share a lot in common, they all inherit from an abstract `BaseOrganization` entity.

When I try to list all the factories, including their mother companies, and then including their mother corporations, I have these two different scenarios :

- **Without including** `BaseOrganization` into the context, code-first creates **three tables** (which corresponds to the **Table-Per-Concrete-Type or TPC** pattern). `Include()` and `ThenInclude()` work fine, and I can list factories and traverse relations as expected.
- **Including** `BaseOrganization` into the context, code-first creates **one table** with a discriminator field (which corresponds to the **Table-Per-Hierarchy or TPH** pattern). `Include()` and `ThenInclude()` throw a `Sequence contains more than one matching element` exception.

This issue (without the inheritance and abstract base class pattern) was already adressed in EF7 Github repo, and had been cleared (see https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/issues/1460).

So I currently don't know if my approach has something wrong, or if this is clearly an issue with EF7 RC1 ? Note that I'd really prefer keeping inheritance so that my SQL model gets far more readable.

Below is the full reproduction code :

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using Microsoft.Data.Entity;

    namespace MultiLevelTest
    {
        // All places share name and Id
        public abstract class BaseOrganization
        {
            public int Id { get; set; }
            public string Name { get; set; }
        }

        // a corporation (eg : Airbus Group)
        public class Corporation : BaseOrganization
        {
            public virtual ICollection<Company> Companies { get; set; } = new List<Company>();
        }

        // a company (eg : Airbus, Airbus Helicopters, Arianespace)
        public class Company : BaseOrganization
        {
            public virtual Corporation Corporation { get; set; }
            public virtual ICollection<Factory> Factories { get; set; } = new List<Factory>();
        }

        // a factory of a company (Airbus Toulouse, Airbus US...)
        public class Factory : BaseOrganization
        {
            public virtual Company Company { get; set; }
        }

        // setup DbContext
        public class MyContext : DbContext
        {
            // if this line is commented, then code first creates 3 tables instead of one, and everything works fine.
            public DbSet<BaseOrganization> BaseOrganizationCollection { get; set; }
            public DbSet<Corporation> Corporations { get; set; }
            public DbSet<Company> Companies { get; set; }
            public DbSet<Factory> Factories { get; set; }

            protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
            {
                optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(
                    @"Server=(localdb)\mssqllocaldb;Database=MultiLevelTest;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true");
            }

            protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
            {
                base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

                modelBuilder.Entity<Corporation>().HasMany(c => c.Companies).WithOne(c => c.Corporation);
                modelBuilder.Entity<Company>().HasMany(c => c.Factories).WithOne(c => c.Company);
                modelBuilder.Entity<Factory>().HasOne(f => f.Company);
            }
        }

        public class Program
        {
            public static void Main(string[] args)
            {
                using (var ctx = new MyContext())
                {
                    ctx.Database.EnsureDeleted();
                    ctx.Database.EnsureCreated();

                    // Add a corporation with companies then factories (this works fine)
                    if (!ctx.Corporations.Any()) CreateOrganizationGraph(ctx);

                    // Get all the factories without including anything (this is still working fine)
                    var simpleFactories = ctx.Factories.ToList();
                    foreach(var f in simpleFactories) Console.WriteLine(f.Name);

                    // Get all the factories including their mother company, then their mother corporation
                    var fullFactories = ctx.Factories
                        .Include(f => f.Company)
                        .ThenInclude(c => c.Corporation)
                        .ToList();
                    foreach (var f in fullFactories) Console.WriteLine($"{f.Company.Corporation.Name} > {f.Company.Name} > {f.Name}");
                }
            }

            public static void CreateOrganizationGraph(MyContext ctx)
            {
                var airbusCorp = new Corporation()
                {
                    Name = "Airbus Group",
                    Companies = new List<Company>()
                            {
                                new Company
                                {
                                    Name = "Airbus",
                                    Factories = new List<Factory>()
                                    {
                                        new Factory {Name = "Airbus Toulouse (FR)"},
                                        new Factory {Name = "Airbus Hambourg (DE)"}
                                    }
                                },
                                new Company
                                {
                                    Name = "Airbus Helicopters",
                                    Factories = new List<Factory>()
                                    {
                                        new Factory {Name = "Eurocopter Marignane (FR)"},
                                        new Factory {Name = "Eurocopter Deutschland (DE)"}
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                };

                ctx.Corporations.Add(airbusCorp);
                ctx.SaveChanges();

            }
        }
    }
```

You will want to include the following NuGet packages :

```
"EntityFramework.Commands": "7.0.0-rc1-final",
"EntityFramework.Core": "7.0.0-rc1-final",
"EntityFramework.MicrosoftSqlServer": "7.0.0-rc1-final"
```

### UPDATE

As said in my own comments, my first workaround would be to avoid including the base type in the DbContext, so that code-first generates schema with TPC pattern (the bug throws only when in TPH strategy).

Problem is that the example above is simpler as my actual implementation, which involves many-to-many relationships defined at base type level.

Since EF7 does not (yet?) support many-to-many relationships, we have to define a link entity which maps two one-to-many relationships on its own.

That mapping entity being defined and used at base type level, code-first still opts for TPH strategy, and then the bug still throws.

In other words, I'm stuck, or I will have to duplicate some logic three times, which is almost like breaking my own leg on purpose !

Comment: I think that my workaround will just be not to include the abstract base type in the DbContext. This will solve the isssue by allowing me to use `Include().ThenInclude()` to load relations. But I don't like the fact that in this case, code-first will generate 3 different tables, because it doesn't reflect inheritance in the SQL schemas, not to count the fact that the shared fields will be repeated in each table.

Comment: I also posted basically the same on the GitHub repo, since I'm pretty much convinced it's an issue with EF7. https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/issues/5033

Answer (score 1):

I think you should not try to use a base class in your case.

Organizations, companies, factories represents different objects and from what I see here, you are trying to refactor code not abstracting object:

If you create a database that store authors and books, both authors and books will have a name and an id but does it make sense to have a base class ?

For sure you are going to save few lines of code but it will make you code less readable.

I think you should use a base class when there is a real inheritance:

For example, you can have a base class `Person` and a `Manager` and `Employee` class that inherits from the Person class because both employees and managers are persons.

For me you just have to remove your base class and It should work as expected :

```
public class Corporation
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<Company> Companies { get; set; } = new List<Company>();
}

public class Company
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Corporation Corporation { get; set; }
    public List<Factory> Factories { get; set; } = new List<Factory>();
}

public class Factory
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Company Company { get; set; }
}

public class MyContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Corporation> Corporations { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Company> Companies { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Factory> Factories { get; set; }

    ...

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Corporation>().HasMany(c => c.Companies).WithOne(c => c.Corporation);
        modelBuilder.Entity<Company>().HasMany(c => c.Factories).WithOne(c => c.Company);
        modelBuilder.Entity<Factory>().HasOne(f => f.Company);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. My example was provided as is for brevity. In my actual implementation, my classes would share a lot more than - of course - just an Id and Name (I also have a base type with interface just for Id and Name, though, and it works fine). As indicated in my update, my classes have a list of Persons, linked as many-to-many relationships. As EF7 does not support these yet, I have some logic to expose a direct access to the Persons collection, and the logic of that has to be repeted unless I factorize this on the Organization base class.

Comment: I also think that on a functional point of view, it makes sense to have corporations, companies and factories inherit from an organization, because... they ARE organizations ! A lot of fields can be shared, like Addresses, Persons, Customers, etc...

Comment: Ok thank for the explanation. It make from a business point of view but your data model should reflect your database. You can have domain objects that reflect this logic

Comment: anyway, EF7 support many to many relationship (this is not perfect...) : https://ef.readthedocs.org/en/latest/modeling/relationships.html#many-to-many. Is this solution acceptable ?

Comment: This is what I said previously : you can model many-to-many rels through a pivot entity, as you would do in a SQL schema. And this is what I did. Hope the remaining features of EF6 like this one will soon be available in EF7. Haven't read the roadmap, though !