# Cast exception with LinqKit's PredicateBuilder on Entity Framework 7

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, entity-framework-core, linqkit

I have a simple EF7 code-first model : `Countries` have `States`, `States` have `Cities`. Relations and inverse relations are defined so that navigation fields and collections can be traversed both ways.

I want to run a text search on all the cities : split the search words to search for each word one after another, have this search to target city names, state names and country names, and make this search inclusive (if I look for 'france germany francisco', cities from France, cities from Germany, and San Francisco will be included in search results).

To achieve that, I am building my search predicate with LinqKit's `PredicateBuilder`.

When I test the predicate building and running code upon a simple in-memory collection of entities, everything works as expected.

When I run it against the Cities DbSet in an Entity Framework 7 context, I have this weird exception (`System.InvalidCastException 'System.Linq.Expressions.FieldExpression' to type 'System.Linq.Expressions.ParameterExpression'`).

I first thought it to be related with LinqKit, but it is actually related to using PredicateBuilder with EF7 when looking for fields involving 2 levels relations:

```
// simple snippet, full code is below.
// the part that causes the exception is when accessing c.State.Country.Name
predicate = predicate.Or(c =>
    c.StateId > 0 &&
    c.State.CountryId > 0 &&
    c.State.Country.Name.Contains(word));
```

On the predicate building code, you will notice I build it at 3 levels :

- Target the text search on **city names** (ok with in-memory and DbSet contexts)
- Target the text search on **state names** (ok with in-memory and DbSet contexts)
- Target the text search on **country names** (ok with in-memory context but **crashes** on DbSet context).

The predicate building process obviously starts with a false init, then OR's with each word and each field target. Before posting here, I tried the following attempts, as read in previous questions related to something similar :

- Call LinqKit's `Expand()` at various steps of the expression building (hint: it didn't help !)
- Previously store the crashing expression in a local variable, and use that `Expression` variable instead of the anonymous lambda (not any better)
- Only use the expression involving the level 2 traversal (the one that crashes) and it still crashed
- Remove the `Name.Contains` part of the level 2 traversal, but keeping the level 2 traversal for Id's. In this case it does not crash (but of course the text lookup is not done).

Here is a full reproduction code (creates a localDb database, seeds it, then runs the crashing code).

It is a .Net 5 console package project, and you will need to add the following NuGet the packages to the project.json file :

```
"dependencies": {
    "LinqKit": "1.1.3.1",
    "EntityFramework.Commands": "7.0.0-rc1-final",
    "EntityFramework.Core": "7.0.0-rc1-final",
    "EntityFramework.MicrosoftSqlServer": "7.0.0-rc1-final"
}
```

C# code of the console app :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using LinqKit;
using Microsoft.Data.Entity;

namespace LinqKitIssue
{
    public abstract class BaseEntity
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }

    public class Country : BaseEntity
    {
        public virtual ICollection<State> States { get; set; } = new List<State>();
    }

    public class State : BaseEntity
    {
        public int CountryId { get; set; }
        public virtual Country Country { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<City> Cities { get; set; } = new List<City>();
    }

    public class City : BaseEntity
    {
        public int StateId { get; set; }
        public virtual State State { get; set; }
        public override string ToString() => $"{Name}, {State?.Name} ({State?.Country?.Name})";
    }

    // setup DbContext
    public class MyContext : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<City> Cities { get; set; }
        public DbSet<State> States { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Country> Countries { get; set; }

        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        {
            optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(
                @"Server=(localdb)\mssqllocaldb;Database=LinqKitIssue;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true");
        }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

            modelBuilder.Entity<Country>().HasMany(c => c.States).WithOne(c => c.Country).HasForeignKey(s => s.CountryId);
            modelBuilder.Entity<State>().HasMany(c => c.Cities).WithOne(c => c.State).HasForeignKey(c => c.StateId);
            modelBuilder.Entity<City>().HasOne(f => f.State);
        }
    }

    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // Seed with all cities
            SeedData.Seed();

            // search parameters
            var searchInput = "los las british france";
            var searchWords = searchInput.Split(' ');
            // will be looking for each word, inclusively
            var predicate = PredicateBuilder.False<City>();
            // iterate to look for each word
            foreach (var word in searchWords)
            {
                // Level 0 : look for the word at each level : city (ok with in-mem and ef)
                predicate = predicate.Or(c => c.Name.Contains(word));
                // Level 1 : then state (ok with in-mem and ef)
                predicate = predicate.Or(c =>
                    c.StateId > 0 &&
                    c.State.Name.Contains(word));
                // Level 2 : then country (ok with in-mem, crashes with ef)
                predicate = predicate.Or(c =>
                    c.StateId > 0 &&
                    c.State.CountryId > 0 &&
                    c.State.Country.Name.Contains(word));
            }

            // apply
            Console.WriteLine($"Search results for : '{searchInput}'");
            using (var ctx = new MyContext())
            {
                var query = ctx.Cities.AsQueryable();
                // includes
                query = query.Include(c => c.State).ThenInclude(s => s.Country);
                // search
                var searchResults = query.Where(predicate).ToList();
                searchResults.ForEach(Console.WriteLine);
            }
        }
    }

    public static class SeedData
    {
        public static void Seed()
        {
            using (var ctx = new MyContext())
            {
                ctx.Database.EnsureDeleted();
                ctx.Database.EnsureCreated();

                // countries
                var us = new Country { Name = "united states" };
                var canada = new Country { Name = "canada" };
                ctx.Countries.AddRange(us, canada);
                ctx.SaveChanges();

                // states
                var california = new State { Name = "california", Country = us };
                var nevada = new State { Name = "nevada", Country = us };
                var quebec = new State { Name = "quebec", Country = canada };
                var bc = new State { Name = "british columbia", Country = canada };
                ctx.States.AddRange(california, nevada, quebec, bc);
                ctx.SaveChanges();

                // Cities
                var sf = new City { Name = "san francisco", State = california };
                var la = new City { Name = "los angeles", State = california };
                var lv = new City { Name = "las vegas", State = nevada };
                var mt = new City { Name = "montreal", State = quebec };
                var vc = new City { Name = "vancouver", State = bc };
                ctx.Cities.AddRange(sf, la, lv, mt, vc);
                ctx.SaveChanges();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Below is the full stack trace (sorry for being in french, but I don't feel like translating it, and the french words are tranparent compared to english ones !).

```
System.InvalidCastException: Impossible d'effectuer un cast d'un objet de type 'System.Linq.Expressions.FieldExpression' en type 'System.Linq.Expressions.ParameterExpression'.
   à Microsoft.Data.Entity.Query.ExpressionVisitors.Internal.IncludeExpressionVisitor.VisitMethodCall(MethodCallExpression expression)
   à System.Linq.Expressions.MethodCallExpression.Accept(ExpressionVisitor visitor)
   à Microsoft.Data.Entity.Query.ExpressionVisitors.ExpressionVisitorBase.Visit(Expression expression)
   à System.Linq.Expressions.ExpressionVisitor.VisitArguments(IArgumentProvider nodes)
   à System.Linq.Expressions.ExpressionVisitor.VisitMethodCall(MethodCallExpression node)
   à Microsoft.Data.Entity.Query.ExpressionVisitors.Internal.IncludeExpressionVisitor.VisitMethodCall(MethodCallExpression expression)
   à System.Linq.Expressions.MethodCallExpression.Accept(ExpressionVisitor visitor)
   à Microsoft.Data.Entity.Query.ExpressionVisitors.ExpressionVisitorBase.Visit(Expression expression)
   à Microsoft.Data.Entity.Query.RelationalQueryModelVisitor.IncludeNavigations(IncludeSpecification includeSpecification, Type resultType, LambdaExpression accessorLambda, Boolean querySourceRequiresTracking)
   à Microsoft.Data.Entity.Query.EntityQueryModelVisitor.IncludeNavigations(QueryModel queryModel, IReadOnlyCollection`1 includeSpecifications)
   à Microsoft.Data.Entity.Query.RelationalQueryModelVisitor.IncludeNavigations(QueryModel queryModel, IReadOnlyCollection`1 includeSpecifications)
   à Microsoft.Data.Entity.Query.EntityQueryModelVisitor.IncludeNavigations(QueryModel queryModel)
   à Microsoft.Data.Entity.Query.EntityQueryModelVisitor.CreateQueryExecutor[TResult](QueryModel queryModel)
   à Microsoft.Data.Entity.Storage.Database.CompileQuery[TResult](QueryModel queryModel)
--- Fin de la trace de la pile à partir de l'emplacement précédent au niveau duquel l'exception a été levée ---
   à Microsoft.Data.Entity.Query.Internal.QueryCompiler.<>c__DisplayClass18_0`1.<CompileQuery>b__0()
   à Microsoft.Data.Entity.Query.Internal.CompiledQueryCache.GetOrAddQuery[TResult](Object cacheKey, Func`1 compiler)
   à Microsoft.Data.Entity.Query.Internal.QueryCompiler.CompileQuery[TResult](Expression query)
   à Microsoft.Data.Entity.Query.Internal.QueryCompiler.Execute[TResult](Expression query)
   à Microsoft.Data.Entity.Query.Internal.EntityQueryProvider.Execute[TResult](Expression expression)
   à Remotion.Linq.QueryableBase`1.GetEnumerator()
   à System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection)
   à System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
   à LinqKitIssue.Program.Main(String[] args) dans d:\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\LinqKitIssue\src\LinqKitIssue\Program.cs:ligne 98
--- Fin de la trace de la pile à partir de l'emplacement précédent au niveau duquel l'exception a été levée ---
   à System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   à Microsoft.Dnx.Runtime.Common.EntryPointExecutor.Execute(Assembly assembly, String[] args, IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
   à Microsoft.Dnx.ApplicationHost.Program.<>c__DisplayClass3_0.<ExecuteMain>b__0()
   à System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.InnerInvoke()
   à System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()
```

Comment: See https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/issues/4597

Comment: That seems to be an actual bug and included in the next milestone (rc2). well nothing else to do than wait, or take a  snapshot from the github repo.

Comment: To my point of view, I still consider this issue open. Turns out that this issue, and the previous one I posted (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36554296/include-theninclude-throws-sequence-contains-more-than-one-matching-element/36585894) were actuel EF7 bugs since resolved in beta builds of EF (which is now called Entity Framework Core 1.0.0). Yet I'm still unable to have it running, but I hope to be soon able to, and will then share it here. Here's the current discussion about it: https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/issues/5033#issuecomment-213602688